# JsonConvert.DeserializeObject blocks UI thread

Tags: .net, vb.net, multithreading, asynchronous, json.net

The following VB.NET code uses the Newtonsoft JSON.NET library and executes in a button click event handler and blocks the UI thread:

```
Dim table As DataTable = 
Await Task.Factory.StartNew(Function() JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(of DataTable)(result))
```

I've tried to use different syntax (Task.Run etc.) but it still blocks the UI thread. What is the correct syntax to use here?

**EDIT**: it turns out the UI is actually blocking when the DataSource is being set for a DataGridView UI component. There are only 500 records in the DataTable used to populate the DataGridView. Why is the UI blocking when performing this task, i.e.

```
Dim dv As DataView = table.DefaultView
DataGridView1.DataSource = dv
```

Thanks

Comment: That appears to be correct is there more code than that in the call that could be causing the block?

Comment: @DoomVroom There is no other code that could be causing the block however the code running the Windows Form is executed inside a plug-in class running inside a large Windows application- could it be that the client application is somehow preventing the plug-in class from creating new threads? How would I go about detecting that? Thanks!

Comment: In my experience with JsonConvert it doesn't take long. I don't know how large of a table you are converting though. I would probably mock up a test deserializing your data table. Just do a Unit test of the table and the deserialize to see how long it takes. See if the test matches your expectations. I am also assuming you are using Async in your function as well, because your code doesn't state it.

Comment: You're blocking on the outer task via a call to `Wait` or `Result`.

Comment: @DoomVroom Thanks- see my update. It looks like the UI hangs when setting the datasource for the DataGridView. Any suggestions on how to solve that?

Comment: Unless you are modifying the default view of table I would try just setting the datagridview.datasource = table. See if that helps. That would be the quickest method. After that you may need to look for any events that would be firing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would try removing the `Async` keyword from your event handler, and using the `ContinueWith` method and see if that helps.
Example:

```
Dim context = TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext()
Dim t = Task.Factory.StartNew(Function() JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(Of DataTable)(result))

t.ContinueWith(Sub(res)
    If res.Result IsNot Nothing Then
        ' Do something with your data table
    End If
End Sub, context)
```

This won't block your UI thread, and you can process the data table when the operation is complete. Keep in mind though, that your event handler will immediately return, and the `ContinueWith` handler will fire at a later time. So you may have to adjust your UI accordingly (disable buttons, etc..)

EDIT:
Updated code example to reflect DoomVroom's suggestion

UPDATE:
In response to the OP's update, I would suggesting creating a view, and loading only a few records in it at first. As the user scrolls or pages, add some more records into it. Adding 500+ records all at once overwhelms the UI thread and you experience the blocking.

Comment: Doing this method should work but if you want to do UI work make sure to use the overload that passes in the UI thread.

Comment: Thanks, I updated my example. You're correct, accessing controls on the UI thread without passing in the UI thread would throw an exception.

Comment: Thanks very much for the suggestion. This still blocks the UI thread for about 8 seconds whilst the datasource for the gridview is being set.

Comment: Yes, since your update says that the blocking is happening after you deserialize, and when you set the datasource to the gridview itself, this won't really do all that much to help.

Comment: The only thing I can suggest now, is to limit the number of rows you set to the gridview. You could do this by implementing some kind of virtual paging by creating a "view" and loading records into it as you scroll or page through your gridview.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
Dim table As DataTable = 
    Await Task.Run(
        Function() JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(of DataTable)(result))

Dim si As ISupportInitialize = DataGridView1
si.BeginInit()
DataGridView1.DataSource = table.DefaultView
si.EndInit()
```

Comment: Thansk! I've tried this but it still blocks around 8 seconds whilst the datasource is being set.

Comment: Try disabling the grid view. Or add to the grid view in bulks.